# iOS - Objective-C: Image manipulation and processing

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, uiimageview, uiimage

I am developing an **iOS application (Objective C)** in which I needed to deal with *image manipulation.*

Functions to do in module of application are,

Take any image (parent-image) that you want to edit. Then put other images like similes, emojies, sticker into that image. The sub-images should be Scalable, Rotatable, Draggable within parent image bounds.

I succeeded to manage sub-images scale, rotate, drag effects.

**But the problem is, during the scaling, rotating, dragging sub-image, the portion of image that lies outside the parent image should become blur or lower its alpha value than the portion of image inside the parent-image.**

*I’ve attached the reference screenshot of the output that I am looking for.*

[This is the reference image of the output, I am looking for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31vVY.png)

Edit: Here is the code snippet.

```
UIImageView* randomView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(130, 200, 100, 100)];
        randomView.image = image; //image coming from gallery
        randomView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
        randomView.alpha = 0.8;

        imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        imageView.opaque = NO;

        randomView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        randomView.opaque = NO;

        [self addPanGesture:randomView];
        [self addPinchGesture:randomView];
        [self addRotateGesture:randomView];

        [imageView addSubview:randomView];
```

Comment: Provide your code and more details about implementation to better understand the issue.

Comment: Try this once: `self.imageView.clipToBounds = YES`

Comment: Please see the edit for code view. @comrade

Answer (score 2):

I think this demo you are asking for...
Check this demo :

http://sugartin.info/2011/10/21/mask-and-crop-of-an-image/

First crop the image by another image shape & then Replace the following Function in the demo to get your requirement like this....

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    UIImage *img =  [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];

    self.image_view.image=[self maskImage:img withMask:[UIImage imageNamed:@"frame.png"]];
    UIImageView *viewImg=[[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:self.image_view.frame];
    viewImg.image=img;
    viewImg.alpha=0.4;
    [self.view addSubview:viewImg];
    [self.view sendSubviewToBack:viewImg];

}
```

This demo gives me this type of result...

[image]

> In case, if you want only masking image function with another Image,
>   [Here](http://iosdevelopertips.com/cocoa/how-to-mask-an-image.html) it is..

```
- (UIImage*) maskImage:(UIImage *)image withMask:(UIImage *)maskImage {

    CGImageRef maskRef = maskImage.CGImage; 

    CGImageRef mask = CGImageMaskCreate(CGImageGetWidth(maskRef),
        CGImageGetHeight(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerComponent(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBitsPerPixel(maskRef),
        CGImageGetBytesPerRow(maskRef),
        CGImageGetDataProvider(maskRef), NULL, false);

    CGImageRef masked = CGImageCreateWithMask([image CGImage], mask);
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:masked];

}
```

Hope this would help.. Let me know if that works or not...Thanks.. :)